# validar campo de texto con mascara en laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5

Quiero validadar unos campos de un formulario, por eje: el campo de texto que tenga la siguiente mascara: 000-0000000-0

Comment: Hola, Gali. Tu pregunta está muy poca detallada. Por favor, muéstranos qué código llevas hecho hasta ahora. Mientras editas tu pregunta, te invito a [hacer el recorrido](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) por el sitio y a consultar la guía [Cómo preguntar](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Ok gracias, lo consultare

Comment: Quieres hacerlo en la parte servidor (php) ? o en la parte cliente (javascript) ?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar [jQuery-Mask-Plugin](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/) y hacer algo como

```
$(function() {
    $("#id_campo").mask('000-0000000-0', {reverse: true});
}
```

[Aquí](https://styde.net/ajax-y-laravel-usando-jquery/) puedes ver como trabajar con JQuery en laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Hola qué tal lo más fácil es ocupar pattern en el input de está forma.

Lo puse así por qué me imagino quieres números entre 0 y 9.

```
<input type="text"  pattern="^[0-9]{3}[\-][0-9]{7}[\-][0-9]{1}" title="000-0000000-0">
```

De querer sólo números 0 sería así:

```
<input type="text"  pattern="^[0]{3}[\-][0]{7}[\-][0]{1}" title="000-0000000-0">
```

Saludos, cuéntame como te fue!

Comment: NO resulto. lo puse pero sale en blanco: <input name="cedula"  class="form-control" type="text"  pattern="^[0]{3}[\-][0]{7}[\-][0]{1}" title="000-0000000-0">

Comment: @Gali que sale en blanco? El input? Aaa quieres que se vea es placeholder lo que necesitas así como lo tienes pero agrégale placeholder="000-0000000-000" el title es para cuando falla la condición del pattern, cuéntame como te fue

Comment: <input name="cedula"  class="form-control" type="text"  class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="000-0000000-0" pattern="^[0]{3}[\-][0]{7}[\-][0]{1}" title="000-0000000-0">

Comment: No funciona: no valida al usuario entrar solo los 000-0000000-0 sino que puede poner todo lo quiere y no es lo que quiero...

Comment: @Gali no te entiendo, cómo?